# C code calling exit() causes ctypes to crash Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I have a piece of `C` code that I wrapped in a `ctypes` interface to call it from Python. All the ctypes interface is doing it calling `main()` for a piece of standalone C code. The `C` code, as an error handling method, will as a last resort call `exit(errorcode)` in a few places. I thought that this would simply be equivalent (from `ctypes` perspective) to exiting `main()` with a nonzero exit code, but instead it crashes everything.

Is there a way to gracefully handle the `exit()` function from `ctypes`, or do I need to rethink how the C side handles errors? Why is the behavior of `exit()` different when C code is called via `ctypes` versus when it is run on its own?

Comment: Well, exit exits the whole program (I.e. CPython interpreter)- so it is not a crash. Using exit for error handling isn’t the most flexible approach in a library.

Comment: For a "standalone C code" with a main(), is it an executable instead of a dynamic library?  If an executable, use the `subprocess` module, not `ctypes`.  In any case, need more detail and example code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: It is a .dll, but constructed so that I can just call main() directly through ctypes. I realize this isn't exactly the intention, and it is slowly getting refactored. I did not realize that exit killed the whole thing - I thought that from the C perspective it was the same as a return from main with a nonzero code

Comment: It is, but the real main is not the one you are calling, but the main of the interpreter.

Comment: @ead aha, that makes more sense now. Thanks for clarifying! Short answer: refactor it and handle errors properly.